# Javascript confirm or alert is not readable by Jaws screen reader. is there any way so that i can make it readale alert by screenreader?

Tags: javascript, jaws-screen-reader

Javascript confirm or alert is not readable by Jaws screen reader. is there any way so that i can make it readale alert by screenreader ?

Comment: This seems to  be a [bug in Chrome that has already been fixed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=779501).

Comment: I am trying to test it in chrome version 92 and my jaws version is 18. Still getting the same issue

Comment: Ah, [looks like it regressed](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1084501&q=alert%20JAWS&can=2)